# Combining every pair of rows into one MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I wrote part of the query and got stuck on final part of it. Code that I have so far:

```
SELECT uid, 
       x, 
       y 
FROM   (SELECT uid, 
               x, 
               y, 
               ( Timediff(Max(ts), Min(ts)) ) idle_time 
        FROM   test 
        WHERE  speed = 0 
        GROUP  BY x, 
                  y, 
                  uid 
        HAVING Count(*) > 0) t 
WHERE  idle_time > 1 
ORDER  BY uid
```

And the resulting table is:

```
----------------------------------
| uId | x        | y             |  
----------------------------------
| 1   | 110      | 20            |  <-- Uid = 1 start position
----------------------------------
| 1   | 220      | 50            |  <-- Uid = 1 end position
----------------------------------
| 2   | 30      | 15             |  <-- Uid = 2 start position
----------------------------------
| 2   | 40      | 22             |  <-- Uid = 2 end position
----------------------------------
```

What I need to get now is:

```
------------------------------------------------------
| uId | x_start | x_end       | y _start    | y_end  |  
------------------------------------------------------
| 1   | 110      | 220        |  20         | 50     |
------------------------------------------------------
| 2   | 30      | 40         |  15          |  22    |
------------------------------------------------------
```

The results **will always come in pairs**. That means there can be multiple lines with the same uId, only pairs needs to be added. I know this is not difficult, any help is appreciated!!

**EDIT:**

Forgot to mention, that X and Y of END is not always bigger than START as in real database map coordinates is used.

Comment: how you know `{ 110 | 20  }` is the start position and not the end position?? or order doesn't matter?

Comment: Database is sorted on timestamp, so 110 | 20 is always the start position and 220 | 50 is the end.

Comment: Not really. You need something to sorted. Dataset are unorder unless you use `ORDER BY` right now you orde by uid, but both have same uId so the order is random

Comment: Please show the sample data with all the columns so that we can suggest different approach.

Comment: Thank you for observation. Let's say in this case order doesn't matter then. My main goal is every pair of lines concatenation into one now.

Comment: In that case, my answer will work.

Comment: @Harshil Doesnt work, because you need a pair. Min/Max doesnt warranty that

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I don't get it. Please explain.

Comment: with pairs `{1, 10} {10,1}`  you will get `MIN(x,y) = {1,1}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a pretty way to do it because you can't use CTE on mySQL

First you need return the timestamp on your inner query

```
------------------------------------------
| uId | x       | y   | ts               |
------------------------------------------
| 1   | 110     | 20  | 2017-11-23 15:01 |
------------------------------------------
| 1   | 220     | 50  | 2017-11-23 16:11 |
------------------------------------------
| 2   | 30      | 15  | 2017-11-24 05:20 |
------------------------------------------
| 2   | 40      | 22  | 2017-11-24 11:30 |
------------------------------------------
```

Then you can write the following query:

for simplicity I will call your `innerQuery` because you have to repeat the code.

```
SELECT q1.uid as uid
       q1.x as x_start,
       q1.y as y_start,
       q2.x as x_end,
       q2.y as y_end
FROM ( innerQuery ) as q1
JOIN ( innerQuery ) as q2
  ON q1.uid = q2.uid
 AND q1.ts < q2.ts
```